# Ajax Loading of Page Without changing the loaded content after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

The situation is that I have links:

Edit Account Info - that points to `http://example.com/user/edit`

I setup a javascript that will only fetch information in the controller then will load it in a template.
I have this code that does the eventhandling

```
$("#lnkEditUser").on("click", 
  function()
  {
    some.settings.edit_profile();
     return false;
  })
```

What it does, is that it replaces the content of a div with the template, 
so I have it loaded, the template and the details from the controller(from the model) via ajax calls.  The problem is that when I try to refresh the page, the content would be its default. Is it possible that when I click on the link the URL will then change to something like:

```
http://example.com/user#edit
```

So even when I refresh the page, the content loaded via ajax will be the same?
If I remove the #edit, it'll be the default?

Comment: u can add like this <a href="#edit">link</a> on click of anchor tag it will get appended to the url

Comment: Expanding upon what fuzionpro has said, you'll need to test for the occurence of the `hash` in the `url string` and then perform logic to make this data load. Something like `if(window.location.hash == 'edit'){ //do template loading }else{ //load default page }`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i did this right, or if there is a better way to do it..

first I check if the hash exist, then get the value of the hash, assigned it to variable `hash` then i removed the hash, maybe i can do also do this `replace("#", "")`. I realize other stuffs while i'm typing this like i should have been converted it `hash` to string right on  the assigning of value. But anyhow, this is how I did it.

```
activeTemplateViaHash : function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        hash = hash.toString().substr(1, hash.toString().length-1);
        var method = new Function('some.settings.' + hash + '()');
        method();
    }
},
```

Comment: please read about [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and `call()`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
activeTemplateViaHash : function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        hash = hash.replace("#", "");
        var method = some.settings[hash]; //find the hash method
        if(method) {  //if the method exists then run it
            method();
        }
        else {
            alert(hash + " function doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
},
```

But instead of relying on hashes like that, I would use `localStorage` or `COOKIES` to store user settings easily.